# A gap added in Gmail, inside a html signature from outlook

Tags: html, outlook, gmail, signature

I've created an html signature I need to use in Outlook. Following recommendations, I've used a table layout, given all images and even td's, tr's and the table itself specific height and width, 0 padding and margin, and even tried adding those in both css and in the old-fashion way on the actual tags.
In outlook, it comes out right, but in gmail it adds a gap between the tr's.
Following the recommendation here: [Gmail displaying gaps between images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890876/gmail-displaying-gaps-between-images), I've tried to add style="display:block;" to the images, still no luck.
Here is the code I use:

```
<table cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" border="0px" width="592px" height="254px" style="border-collapse:collapse; border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; width:592px; height:254px;">
<tr cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="592px" height="90px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:592px; height:90px;">
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="83px" height="90px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:83px; height:90px;">&nbsp;</td>
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="150px" height="90px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:150px; height:90px;"><img src="new_sig.files/sig2.png" width="150px" height="90px"></td>
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="359px" height="90px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:359px; height:90px;"><img src="new_sig.files/sig3.png" width="359px" height="90px"></td>
</tr>
<tr cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="592px" height="64px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:592px; height:64px;">
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="83px" height="64px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:83px; height:64px;"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img style="border:none;" src="new_sig.files/sig4.png" width="83px" height="64px"></a></td>
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="150px" height="64px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:150px; height:64px;"><img src="new_sig.files/sig5.png" width="150px" height="64px"></td>
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="359px" height="64px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:359px; height:64px;"><img src="new_sig.files/sig6.png" width="359px" height="64px"></td>
</tr>
<tr cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="592px" height="100px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:592px; height:100px;">
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="83px" height="100px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:83px; height:100px;"><img src="new_sig.files/sig7.png" width="83px" height="100px"></td>
<td cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" width="150px" height="100px" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; width:150px; height:100px;"><img src="new_sig.files/sig8.png" width="150px" height="100px"></td>
<td cellspacing="0px" style="padding:0px 5px 0px 15px; margin:0px; width:339px; height:100px;line-height:16px; font-size:12px;color:#4f4f4f;font-family:arial;" >
Name LastName<br/>
Description<br/><br/>
<a href="http://www.site.com" style="color:#0875a4;">www.site.com</a>
<img src="new_sig.files/phone_icon.png" width="18px" height="28px"/>
972-(0)3-6960556
<img src="new_sig.files/mail_icon.png" width="18px" height="28px"/>
<a href="mailto:name@site.com" style="color:#0875a4;">name@site.com</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now, the code gmail reads, apparently, goes like this:

```
<table width="592" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 444pt; border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr style="min-height: 67.5pt;">
<td width="83" style="width: 62.25pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 67.5pt;">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">&nbsp;</span></p>
</td>
<td width="150" style="width: 112.5pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 67.5pt;">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
<img height="90" width="150" src=""></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p></td>
<td width="359" style="width: 269.25pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 67.5pt;">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
<img height="90" width="359" src=""></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p></td></tr>
<tr style="min-height: 48pt;">
<td width="83" style="width: 62.25pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 48pt;">
<p class="MsoNormal"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;; color: blue; text-decoration: none;">
<img height="64" width="83" border="0" src=""></span></a><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p></td><td width="150" style="width: 112.5pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 48pt;"><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
<img height="64" width="150" border="0" src=""></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p></td>
<td width="359" style="width: 269.25pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 48pt;"><p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
<img height="64" width="359" border="0" src=""></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p></td></tr>
<tr style="min-height: 75pt;">
<td width="83" style="width: 62.25pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 75pt;">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
<img height="100" width="83" border="0" src=""></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p></td>
<td width="150" style="width: 112.5pt; padding: 0in; min-height: 75pt;">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;">
<img height="100" width="150" border="0" src=""></span><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;,&quot;serif&quot;;"></span></p></td>
<td width="339" style="width: 254.25pt; padding: 0in 3.75pt 0in 11.25pt; min-height: 75pt;">
<p style="line-height: 12pt;" class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 9pt; color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">Name LastName<br>Description<br><br><a target="_blank" href="http://www.site.com">
<span style="color: rgb(8, 117, 164);">www.site.com</span></a> </span>
<span style="font-size: 9pt; color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">
<img height="28" width="18" border="0" src=""></span>
<span style="font-size: 9pt; color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">972-(0)3-6960556 </span>
<span style="font-size: 9pt; color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">
<img height="28" width="18" border="0" src=""></span>
<span style="font-size: 9pt; color: rgb(79, 79, 79);">
<a target="_blank" href="mailto:name@site.com">
<span style="color: rgb(8, 117, 164);">name@site.com</span></a> </span></p></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I tried also giving the whole table line-height of 0, but that didn't work either.
The 2 images in the last cell, btw, aren't displayed in gmail for some reason.

---

update: didn't really notice this received more answers till now. we ended up simplifying the design/code a bit, and i stopped checking this page after a while. not sure if any of the solutions here would have worked, but i see they helped other people. thnx anyways :)

Answer (score 13):

For table cells that only contain an image, set the line-height to 0

```
<td style="line-height:0"><img ... /></td>
```

( Email On Acid was a good tip. )

Comment: @Tim, and for table cells that contain text? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't replicate the problem by sending an email to my Gmail account, but I did see the problem while checking the HTML in the Opera browser.

Try adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the problematic `<TD>`. It did the trick for Opera.

That is, of course, without seeing the images, but the vertical align shouldn't brake anything.

You may also want to check out this tool:
http://www.emailonacid.com/

The free version allows you to check AOL Web, Gmail and Outlook 2003.

Comment: It does fix the problem in firebug, but when I send it again via outlook it for some reason removes the vertical-align. I tried just now adding valign the td, it removes that also..

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--
        p.MsoNormal {
            margin: 0px !important;
        }
    -->
</style>
```

It should override the styling that unwillingly appears in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you tried adding style="display:block" to your images but I don't see this in your code.  A couple of things fixed these situations for me in Gmail:

- Add border="0" and style="display:block" into every  element
- When specifying widths and heights in attributes (rather than in the "style" attribute) don't include "px", just the number

So if you ensure all of your images are in the following format it should remove those gaps (assuming they aren't put there by incorrect height values).

```
<img alt="something" src="http://somewhere.com/image.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" style="display:block;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked for me is I sum up each and every solution given here

did something like :

```
        <td rowspan="2" style="line-height:0">
<img src="images/myimage.jpg" width="426" height="183" alt=""border="0" style="display:block;" />
</td>
```

and it worked fine for me...