# GMail, MailChimp adding spacing between images in tables

Tags: css, gmail, mailchimp

I'm having trouble with email formatting for emails received in the GoogleMail web client.

Space is added after the images in the table making gaps in my content, exactly the same as this question - [Gmail displaying gaps between images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890876/gmail-displaying-gaps-between-images).

Adding the inline style 'display: block;' fixes the issue in the MailChimp preview.

However the inline image styles are being removed at some point between me previewing them in the MailChimp and receiving them in my inbox, re-adding the inline CSS manually fixes it again so that's definitely the issue.

Style in MailChimp Template

```
<img src="" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" style=" width: 700px; display: block;">
```

Style when read by GoogleMail

```
<img src="IMAGE_PATH" alt="" border="0" width="700" height="665">
```

Is there a reason this is happening? Is it on MailChimps or GoogleMails side?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Gmail is stripping out the style attribute, because it doesn't like something.

A few things to try:

1) Remove the extra space at the beginning of your style declaration:

```
<img src="" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" 
     mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" 
     style="width:700px; display:block;">
```

2) Specify `!important`: 
(reference:http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3652/gmail-strips-out-inline-css)

```
<img src="" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" 
     mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" 
     style="width:700px; display:block !important;">
```

3) Try adding `line-height` to the containing `td` element:
(reference: http://www.webdevdoor.com/html-css/html-email-development-tips/)

```
<td style="line-height:0px;">
   <img src="" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image"
         mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" 
         style="width:700px; display:block;"></td>
```

**One more to try**

4) Add `width="700"` attribute (maybe toss `height` in as well) to `img` tag and only specify `display:block;` in `style` attribute:

```
<img src="" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" 
     mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" 
     width="700" height="665" style="display:block;">
```

**Here's another one**

5) The HTML5 doctype can cause rendering problems. Try using this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

**Last one...**

6) Just noticed that you set `mc:allowdesigner=""` and `mc:allowtext=""`, what happens if you remove the `=""` from those two?

```
<img src="" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" 
     mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext 
     style="width:700px; display:block;">
```

Hopefully, one of these will work for you.

Comment: I have tried all of these solutions already except the line-height one but I'm 99% certain it won't work, I will get back to you, cheers

Comment: I've tried all of these now, the style is still being removed (and I can't really have a fixed height, the image is independent of the template (the template is reused with different images) so fixed height really would be a last resort

Comment: Why don't you post your template code and drop it into http://jsfiddle.net/ ...maybe there's something else going on, or there's another way to structure it to avoid the issue.

Comment: I built the template code using a browser to preview, then tested and refactored with help from the MailChimp preview. There's no other way as emails = tables = nightmares

Comment: Sure. You could still post the code, and let another set of eyes look at it, and possibly try it in MailChimp. I understand *not* wanting to give away the keys to the castle, but if you are genuine about your request for help...you need to at least let people into the foyer.

Comment: You mentioned that you can't have a fixed height for your image, but did you try specifying the height attribute for the image along with the `width="700"` and `style="display:block;"`...just to see if it worked? If it clears up the issue, you can always tackle the different images issue with various techniques.

Comment: The doctype is <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I have tried specifying the height on the image but without display: block it still adds extra space at the end of the cell

Comment: those mc:... attributes are removed by MailChimp before the email is sent, they specify what part of the email is editable and are not actually part of the email which is sent

Comment: Share the template, let others try it and see if they run into the same problem.

Comment: +1 - It worked perfectly using the line-height + the display block on the image. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For me it's help (adding <p style="margin: 0;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;"> in <td>):

```
<td><p style="margin: 0;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;"><img src="{IMG_PATH}/w_bottom.jpg" 
alt="" height="8" width="653"/></p></td>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This was exactly the problem for me, Gmail was automatically adding the paragraph where my code lacked it.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely *not* the case that Gmail will always strip out `style="display: block"` on images. As @Fletch states, the simplest thing would be to do this:

```
<img src="" id="headerImage width="700" style="display: block;">
```

...rather than setting the `width` using an inline style. Outlook 07/10 won't obey widths set using `style` anyway in some instances, so its safest to set it that way. Or just leave out width altogether (necessary for a responsive email design).

You'll need to put your complete code somewhere, as it must be something else within the HTML causing problems, as the above code works perfectly.

Comment: I know the code above works and I've had other emails where it hasn't stripped out style='display: block;' as noted above I've tried it with and without the width and many other combinations

Comment: And the height in the second image in my question is automatically added by MailChimp when you add the image in the MailChimp editor

Comment: Hence needing the complete code for your template: I've sent emails through MailChimp with no problem.

Comment: Were they images with the mc:edit attribute CherryFlavourPez?

Comment: Sam, at the very least, you should supply some surrounding code in order to troubleshoot this issue. Maybe you have an editable image inside another editable content area? Otherwise, it's pretty much like throwing darts in the dark. My aim is a lot better when I can see the target. I'm sure most would agree.

Comment: Yep, they were editable images. I'd bet that @fletch is on the right lines (it's easy to accidentally nest MC editable attributes that shouldn't be). Is there a reason you *don't* want to share more of the code? It's kind of the nature of HTML that you can't keep it hidden.

Comment: You are missing the end quote for your ID attribute in this example.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this for a long while, added this to the  section.

```
table{
        border:0px;
        border-spacing:0px;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
td{
        line-height:0px;
    }
tr{
        display:block;
}
```

I hope this solves your issue, as this was quite the frustrating problem for me.

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Gmail automatically adds a paragraph tag to the table data tags. Adding a paragraph tag with styles worked for me.

```
<td><p style="margin: 0;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;"><img /></p><td>
```