# Space between images when viewed on gmail formatted in html

Tags: space, html-table

I have been trying to create an html email. When viewed on gmail it shows spaces between images. I have tried all possible that I could find on internet but did not work. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>#</title>

<style>
    table {border-collapse:collapse;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td align="center"> <font size="1" face="Arial" color="#666666">If you are unable to see this message <a href="#" target="_blank">Click Here </a></font></td></tr>
 </table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none;" align="center" width="600" border="0">
  <tr><td><img src="images/bg-1.jpg" alt="Call: 9212612255" border="0" style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; vertical-align:top;"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td><img src="images/bg-2.jpg" alt="We support all Microsoft windows desktop operating system all software and hardware, Networking peripherals and internet are also supported" border="0" style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; vertical-align:top;"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td><img src="images/bg-3.jpg" border="0" alt="Computer Support By Microsoft Certified Engineers" style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; vertical-align:top;"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="images/bg-4.jpg" border="0" alt="Support available for any desktop or laptop Branded or Non-Branded" style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; vertical-align:top;"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="http://www.codeslab.com" target="_blank" style="border:none; text-decoration:none"><img src="images/bg-5.jpg" border="0" alt="Visit Our Website" style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; vertical-align:top;"/></a></td></tr>
     <tr><td><img src="images/bg-6.jpg" border="0" alt="For more details mail us at info@codeslab.com" style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; vertical-align:top;"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td><img src="images/bg-7.jpg" border="0" alt="Computer Support By Microsoft Certified Engineers" style="display:block; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; vertical-align:top;"/></td></tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600" border="0" style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none;">
    <tr>
       <td align="center">
           <font size="1" face="Arial" color="#666666">To unsubscribe mailing list, click <a href="http://codeslab.com/contact-us.php" target="_blank">here</a></font>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to code like it's 1996. Think all inline styles. Set `line-height` equal to your desired `height` and setting margins and padding to 0.

Comment: not related. It's Gmail's "design" to leave gaps between images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gmail displaying gaps between images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890876/gmail-displaying-gaps-between-images)

Answer (score 0):

It is a common eDM technique to set all `<img>` tag with CSS `display: block` to solve this Gmail display issue. Also, remove `vertical-align` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good guide for HTML e-mail support:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

If you are setting `img` elements to `display: block;` then the `vertical-align` property does not work. So, try removing `display: block` from images only.

Also, keep in mind that once you make changes to this so it works in Gmail it may break in Outlook or Yahoo! or Hotmail etc. So, test thoroughly.