# Create HTML Email with images only - gaps in gmail

Tags: html, image, gmail, dreamweaver, newsletter

I made it through photoshop and sliced it. I have no idea on what I'm doing.
Any help appreciated

here is the html http://pastie.org/7703074

there are gaps above and below the images when its in gmail. But there aren't any gaps on the left and right. I've tried style display block but that doesnt help

I want to get rid of the gaps

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: there are gaps above and below the images when its in gmail. But there aren't any gaps on the left and right. I've tried style display block but that doesnt help.

Comment: I want to get rid of the gaps

Comment: Looks like you want to create one giant image out of several pieces, each piece in its own cell of the table, and everything you've tried has resulted in gaps between the images.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gmail issue -- see [Gmail displaying gaps between images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890876/gmail-displaying-gaps-between-images?rq=1)

The first thing I notice is that the rows of your table don't have the same number of columns. How many columns are you intending to have in your table? Each row should have that many columns defined.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't know anything about tables and columns. I just designed it in Photoshop and sliced it.I've already looked at that post but style="display: block doesn't help me.

Comment: I guess I'll just scrap it now and learn more. Do you have any suggestions on where I can learn how to make email newsletters?